# How to get the count of a Particular Subview in a UIView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, subviews

I want the count of a particular subview inside a UIView. I am adding some multiple textviews to my view and I want the count of the total UITextviews added to the view? I am able to iterate inside the subviews of the array but not able to find the exact count of the UITextViews. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!!!

```
-(NSUInteger)getTotalNumberOfTextViewsAddedInTheView{

NSUInteger count = 0;

for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {

        count ++;
    }
}

return count;
}
```

Comment: but note that in your example the textviews have to be a **direct** subview of `self.view` to be taken into account!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2:

```
func numberOfTexViewInView(superView: UIView)-> Int{

        var count = 0

        for _view in superView.subviews{

            if (_view is UITextView){
                count++
            }

        }

        return count
    }
```

Objective C:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfTexViewInView:(UIView *)superView{

    NSUInteger count = 0;

    for (UIView *view in superView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            count ++;
        }
    }

    return count;

}
```

Pass your main view in which your UITexView added as parameter to the function and get the result.